# Fragment ListView with Checkbox strange behavior

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `ListView` with `Checkbox` inside a `Fragment` that extends `FragmentList`. The strange behavior is multiple items get checked when one item is clicked.
Strangely, when the list is scrolled, some item gets automatically selected or deselected and I have no `ScrollListener` set.

Here's the code :

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk);
            if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
            } else {
                mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
            mCallback.onArticleSelected(i, isChoice);
        }
    });
}
```

Required:
[image]
<sub>(source: [windrealm.org](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/planets-fragmentactivity.png))</sub>

Comment: Listview's views are recycled. If listview recycle a view with checked state, new view will be in checked state. So, you need to save your checked status as list and update view whenever you create. Mostly, we use SparseBooleanArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView`'s items recycle while you are scrolling. You should put a `boolean` parameter (isChecked) to your `ListView` row object then in your getView method u should initialize your `CheckBox` with that `boolean` parameter. For example:

Assume that your row object:

```
public class Trial{

    public String title;

    public boolean isChecked;

}
```

In your `ListView` adapter's getView method, you should check `isChecked` parameter of your object:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_listview_item, parent, false);

    Trial item = items.get(position);

    yourHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    yourHolder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked);

    return view;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not implementing any holder or any row object since I'm extending `ListFragment`. The `OnClick` is set inside the `OnStart` method like it is shown in the post (edited).

Comment: And so what are you showing in the listview? You have not any object list?

Comment: It's a simple list with a TextView and a CheckBox. See the updated answer.